# Añadir un parametro a una url en javascript

Tags: javascript, url, parametros

En primer lugar gracias por leerme.

Gracias por tu aclaración, como podrás comprobar, estoy empezando en esto de Javascript.

Te explico:

Web de un hotel, tengo un carrusel de ofertas en el que van pasando ofertas, por lo que hay varios DIVS dentro del carrusel:

```
<div class="smrt-carousel-item 16 slick-slide slick-active" data-slick-index="1" aria-hidden="false" style="width: 1137px;">
        <div class="smrt-url"><a href="/en/reservations/?price_group=16&amp;kd=y" class="btn btn-primary"> Book now</a></div>
</div>

<div class="smrt-carousel-item 32 slick-slide slick-active" data-slick-index="1" aria-hidden="false" style="width: 1137px;">
        <div class="smrt-url"><a href="/en/reservations/?price_group=32&amp;kd=y" class="btn btn-primary"> Book now</a></div>
</div>

<div class="smrt-carousel-item 48 slick-slide slick-active" data-slick-index="1" aria-hidden="false" style="width: 1137px;">
        <div class="smrt-url"><a href="/en/reservations/?price_group=48&amp;kd=y" class="btn btn-primary"> Book now</a></div>
</div>
```

Como verás, cada div (.smrt-carousel-item) muestra un número diferente (16, 32, 48), que se muestra como parámetro **price_group=** en la url.

Me gustaría poder hacer lo siguiente:

Si el numero es 16, añadir a la url (justo al final) el parámetro con esta fecha **&date_in=03-12-21**

Y si es 32 añadir otra fecha: **&date_in=03-11-21**

Todo esto cuando la página se ha cargado.

No sé si me he expresado con claridad.

Muy agradecido de antemano.

Comment: `window.location` es para cambiar la URL de la ventana actual. Aquí se trata de un elemento del DOM, tendrías que alcanzar ese elemento y cambiar su atributo `href`. Para alcanzarlo, puedes asignarle un `id` o usar otro método, según el contexto en el que se encuentre. La pregunta es, ¿puedes modificarlo, asignádole un `id`? Conviene siempre poner el código en el contexto en el que se encuentra para ver qué opción podría ser mejor.

Comment: Otro aspecto que no aparece en tu pregunta es a partir de qué hay que actualizar el valor del `href`¿cuando se carga la página, cuando se hace click en algún elemento, cuando se escribe en alguna parte, etc?

Comment: El área de abajo es sólo para respuestas. Para cualquier aclaración sobre la pregunta puedes pulsar en [edit]  y ampliar aclaraciones, código o lo que sea necesario. Me pregunto por qué no lo haces al construir los elementos, sería más simple así, que intentando modificar algo que ya conoces de antemano. Por ejemplo, ¿dónde se determina el precio? Allí podrías agregar, junto con el precio, el otro parámetro que necesitas.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Como ya dije en comentarios, esto convendría mejor hacerlo en el contexto donde creas el DOM. Allí se conocen ya los precios de antemano, porque de hecho vienen en el parámetro `price_group` del tu elemento `href`. Allí podrías implementar la lógica que explico más abajo y traer los elementos ya armados del todo.

Si no es posible y hay que hacerlo sí o sí una vez la página esté cargada, entonces te muestro una forma de hacerlo.

El código está comentado en cada lugar, para que entiendas lo que se ha hecho.

```js
/*
  Usaremos un objeto para asociar los valores
  que deberá tomar el parámetro según el precio
  esto permitirá actualizar el código,
  para que asuma cualquier otro precio
  únicamente agregándolo al objeto
*/
var mDates = {
  16: "03-12-21",
  32: "03-11-21"
};

/*
  Aquí seleccionamos los elementos a
  que hay dentro de los div
  que tienen la clase smrt-url
*/
var smrt = document.querySelectorAll('div.smrt-url a');
smrt.forEach((a) => {
  /*
    Obtenemos el query string del elemento
    search busca sólo los datos que hay después de ?
    OJO: esta función no está en algunos navegadores antiguos
  */
  let params = new URLSearchParams(a.search);
  /*
    Obtenemos el valor de price_group
    para verificarlo en el objeto mDates
  */
  var price = params.get('price_group');
  /*
    Si está en el objeto modificaremos el href
  */
  if (mDates.hasOwnProperty(price)) {
    a.href += `&date_in=${mDates[price]}`;
  }
  /*
    Sólo para verificar
  */
  console.log(a.search);
});
```

```html
<div class="smrt-carousel-item 16 slick-slide slick-active" data-slick-index="1" aria-hidden="false" style="width: 1137px;">
  <div class="smrt-url"><a href="/en/reservations/?price_group=16&amp;kd=y" class="btn btn-primary"> Book now</a></div>
</div>

<div class="smrt-carousel-item 32 slick-slide slick-active" data-slick-index="1" aria-hidden="false" style="width: 1137px;">
  <div class="smrt-url"><a href="/en/reservations/?price_group=32&amp;kd=y" class="btn btn-primary"> Book now</a></div>
</div>

<div class="smrt-carousel-item 48 slick-slide slick-active" data-slick-index="1" aria-hidden="false" style="width: 1137px;">
  <div class="smrt-url"><a href="/en/reservations/?price_group=48&amp;kd=y" class="btn btn-primary"> Book now</a></div>
</div>
```

### Notas finales

Al probar el código, los query string quedarán así:

```
?price_group=16&kd=y&date_in=03-12-21
?price_group=32&kd=y&date_in=03-11-21
?price_group=48&kd=y
```

Si se necesita también un valor para `48`, **sólo tienes que agregarlo al principio en el objeto `mDate`, en forma de par llave:valor**. Por ejemplo, si pones algo así: `48: "02-15-21"`, los elementos que tengan el precio `48` agregarán `&date_in=02-15-21`. Y si hace falta agregar más precios, pues lo mismo... Es un código portable y fácil de mantener.

querySelectoAll()  y URLSearchParams() son funciones relativamente nuevas de Javascript, puede que no funcionen en navegadores antiguos. Si estás programando para navegadores antiguos, deberás buscar otras alternativas. Aquí puedes ver el nivel de compatibilidad para cada una:

1. [querySelectorAll()](https://caniuse.com/queryselector)
2. [URLSearchParams()](https://caniuse.com/urlsearchparams)

Comment: Perdona, es la primera vez que utilizo esta herramienta, poco a poco me iré haciendo con ella. Infinitas gracias, voy a echar un vistazo a todo lo que me dices y te comento!

Comment: A. Cedano, no te puedo decir mas que ESPECTACULAR. Funciona a la perfección, estoy muy agradecido porque lo he entendido perfectamente. Un saludo enorme!

Comment: @Rob me alegro de que te haya servido. Saludos.